# is it possible to run function created through Function constructor under function scope rather than global scope

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function name in string format and want to convert it into function reference.

I can use eval or Function constructor or window[name] to convert string into proper function reference.

But, i don't want to expose the function names as global i.e on window object. I'm planning to create functions wrapped under anonymous function. But, if i use Function constructor, it's not running under the anonymous function scope.

```
(function(){
    var k = function(){alert(1);};
    var kRef = new Function("return k");
    kRef();
})()
```

But, if i use eval instead of Function constructor, it's running under the scope of anonymous function.

```
(function(){
    var k = function(){alert(1);};
    var kRef = eval("k");
    kRef();
})()
```

As we are creating the function using Function constructor inside the anonymous function, why is it not running in function scope? why does eval running under anonymous function scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually intended. Quoting [**the doc**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function):

> Note: Functions created with the `Function` constructor do not create
>   closures to their creation contexts; they always are created in the
>   global scope. When running them, they will only be able to access
>   their own local variables and global ones, not the ones from the scope
>   in which the `Function` constructor was called. This is different from
>   using `eval` with code for a function expression.

This description, in turn, merely rephrases the one given in the [standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.2.1):

> **15.3.2.1** *new Function (p1, p2, … , pn, body)*
>
> [...]
>   11. Return a new Function object created as specified in 13.2 passing
>   P as the FormalParameterListopt and body as the FunctionBody. **Pass
>   in the Global Environment as the Scope parameter and strict as the
>   Strict flag.**

I'm not sure, however, why don't you just use a hash of functions instead of trying to eval them into existence. For example:

```
var method = {
  first: function() { alert('I am first'); },
  second: function() { console.log('I am second'); }
};
```

... then choose the function to use based on some criterias:

```
method[thatShouldBeUsed]();
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for pointing to the reference. I can make use of hash as you mentioned. Thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an object to store the functions:

```
var funcs = {func1 : function(x1, x2){ ... },
             func2 : function(x1, x2){ ... },
             ...
             funcN : function(x1, x2){ ... }};
```

then you can access them by name

```
var result = funcs[name](x1, x2);
```

all this without polluting the global object.